# Convert from 4 decimal places to 2

Tags: php, format, rounding

I have a display page where the values coming from database for the rate field is in the format
2.0000
3.5600
now I have to show them as
2.00
3.56
if I use round($rate, 2) it displays as
2 and
3.56
which doesn't work for me.
Any help will be appericiated

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php - Not 100% sure that you are using php

Comment: Please tag your question with the programming language you use.

Comment: Why do you need it?? `number_format` will return `string` output.

Comment: Found the solution
$newrates = number_format((float)$rates, 2, '.', '');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution
$newrates = number_format((float)$rates, 2, '.', '');